# Search in BindingList<T> with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

Why is this warning?

```
BindingList<ClassName> lst = List.Select(obj => obj.Number == "NN").ToList<ClassName>();
```

.................................................

List:

```
BindingList<ClassName> List = new BindingList<ClassName>();
```

Erro:

System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean `Where` instead of `Select`?

```
List.Select(obj => obj.Number == "NN")
```

is a projection where for each item in the list it returns the string `"NN"` - you now have a sequence of n-times-`"NN"`; you then try to force this into a list of `ClassName`. You then *further* attempt to cast a `List<ClassName>` to `BindingList<ClassName>`, but there is no relationship between them other than `IList<T>`

I expect you mean:

```
BindingList<ClassName> lst = new BindingList<ClassName>(
        List.Where(obj => obj.Number == "NN").ToList());
```

Comment: @mah_85 what do you want to do?

Comment: No. Search to BindingList ----> BindingList<ClassName> lst

Comment: @mah_85 I have no idea what the above comment means

Answer (score 1):

`ToList<T>()` LINQ method converts enumerable into `List<T>`, not into `BindingList<T>`

Comment: maybe BindingList<ClassName> lst = new BindingList<ClassName>(List.Where(obj => obj.Number == "NN"));

Comment: Error:     
The best overloaded method match for 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<ClassName>.BindingList(System.Collections.Generic.IList<ClassName>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @man_85, BindingList<ClassName> lst = new BindingList<ClassName>(List.Where(obj => obj.Number == "NN").ToList());   --- what about this one? :)

Comment: Did my last comment not helped you?